# Aligning text and edit uicontrols

Tags: matlab, formatting, alignment, uicontrol

I am creating GUI and I want to have inputs and results there.

I have `text` fields as labels and `edit` or `popup` for inputs. When I have

```
uicontrol('style','text','string','foo','units','centimeters','position',[1 1 1 0.5]);
uicontrol('style','edit','string','foo','units','centimeters','position',[2 1 1 0.5]);
```

I get the `foo` strings slightly misaligned, baseline of the `text` field is slightly above the baseline of `edit`/`pop` field.

How can I align those fields?

Comment: To vertically center the text in the `text uicontrol` you will need to access the underlying Java directly. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225543/how-to-align-text-to-the-top-of-the-button-in-matlab-gui) shows the general approach. Modifying the background color of the `edit uicontrol` has no affect, MATLAB forces the color to White while the control is enabled.

Comment: @excaza Would you like to expand it to the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this requires accessing the underlying Java. The method is similar to [Amro's approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8232840/2748311) for a `pushbutton` and utilizes the external [`findjobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) function:

```
h.t = uicontrol('style','text','string','foo','units','centimeters','position',[1 1 1 0.5]);
h.e = uicontrol('style','edit','string','foo','units','centimeters','position',[2 1 1 0.5]);
jh = findjobj(h.t);
jh.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.JLabel.CENTER)
```

Unfortunately, this is still off by a pixel or two:

[image: yay]

I'd say just bump the text box by pixel, as necessary:

```
oldunits = get(h.t, 'Units');
set(h.t, 'Units', 'Pixels');
pos = get(h.t, 'Position');

pos(2) = pos(2) + 1;

set(h.t, 'Position', pos)
set(h.t, 'Units', oldunits)
```

Which gives us:

[image: yay2]

---

Edit: Modifying the `BackgroundColor` property of the edit box has no effect (though setting it to `none` makes it a black box...), and the box will remain the default color. Per The MathWorks, this is a [design decision](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/65-why-does-the-backgroundcolor-of-an-editable-textbox-remain-white-when-it-has-been-set-to-another-col):

> This is a expected behavior in the way that MATLAB displays the
>   `BackgroundColor` for editable text objects.

This could also most likely be updated by leveraging the underlying Java, but I'm not familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Jlabel, which is a Javacomponent. I have found the uicomponent from undocumentedMatlab helpful. You can download it from Mathworks File Exchange using this link:https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14583-uicomponent-expands-uicontrol-to-all-java-classes

See this example:

```
figure(1);clf;

[txt1, txt2] = uicomponent(gcf, 'style','JLabel'); % simple spinner with initial value
set(txt1, 'Text', 'Test', 'units','centimeters','position',[1 1 1 1]);
set(txt2, 'horizontalAlignment', javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
set(txt2, 'VerticalAlignment', javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

uicontrol('style','edit','string','foo','units','centimeters','position',[2 1 1 1]);
```

It can create a UI like below:

[image]